# Parent Asynctask wait the asynctask's child

Tags: android

This my situation I had an **asynctask (1)** wich run another **asynctask(2)**
I need that **asynctask(1)** wait untill **asynctask(2)** finish, to be more clear the result of **asynctask(2)** is used in the result of **asynctask(1)**

I did this trick in **asynctask(1)**:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {

        Log.e(" nbr key : "+Utils1.nbr_cle,"");
        Log.e("*=======*","Démarrage de l'application *=======*");
    do {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
            Log.e("======>", "Not  Finished yet !");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        while (!taskFinished);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

in **asynctask(2)**

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
           SplashActivity.taskFinished = true;
            int myBox_size = activityBox.realm.where(MyBox.class).findAll().size();
            Log.e("MyBox Finished ","Size of mybox :" +myBox_size );


    }
```

but it's not working :/

Comment: Any reason why you cant just use one Asynctask instead of 2 to handle all the required logic in a background thread and then posting its results? You could use a CountDownLatch inside a new Thread in a try/catch/finally block (finally block handling all updates)? Pass reference to the CountDownLatch into each asynctask, counting down when each completes).

Comment: Listen bro, the first asynctask give me an id which I'll use to send a request using the second Asynctask, is that possible using one Asyncktask ?

Comment: @Eupho08, It would depend if you made a blocking call? I didn't know we were related? I have suggested a via approach using a New Thread and CountDownLatch.

Comment: Ok thank's, so can you give me an example to my situation, I need more code to CountDownLatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is running the **second** **Asyncktask** in PostExcute of **AsynckTask** **(1)** to avoid this problem, because running the **second** **AsyncTask** into the **first one** is not a good idea.

If someone want to use **CountDownLatch**:
This is some refs : 
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/CountDownLatch.shtml

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea and likely won't work because of the way `AsyncTask` thread executors work.  By default your `AsyncTask` instances are serialized, so one must finish before another one starts.

Comment: Yes, but in this situation what I can do ? because the child asynkTask must finish first because the result is using by the parent asynktask

Comment: You will either need to change the executor in use for `AsyncTask` within your app; or, use your own threads and thread executor.